# Reading multiple JSon records to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm pretty n00b with JS programming so this is maybe a stupid question, but after hours of searching I haven't find a working solution from the net.

I have multiple JSON feeds. Server is giving one multilayer JSON record per url like this (data is imaginary test data):

- http://address/ci/c/1 gives:

  `{
  "LGICUS01OperationResponse": {
  "ca": {
    "ca_phone_mobile": "07799 123456",
    "ca_request_id": "01ICUS",
    "ca_return_code": 0,
    "ca_dob": "11.07.1950",
    "ca_last_name": "Pandy",
    "ca_num_policies": 0,
    "ca_phone_home": "01962 811234",
    "ca_email_address": "A.Pandy@beebhouse.com",
    "ca_house_name": "",
    "ca_policy_data": "",
    "ca_customer_num": 1,
    "ca_first_name": "Andrew",
    "ca_house_num": "34",
    "ca_postcode": "PI101OO"
  }
  }
  }`
- http://address/ci/c/2 gives:

  `{
  "LGICUS01OperationResponse": {
  "ca": {
    "ca_phone_mobile": "123",
    "ca_request_id": "01ICUS",
    "ca_return_code": 0,
    "ca_dob": "30.09.1965",
    "ca_last_name": "Tracey",
    "ca_num_policies": 0,
    "ca_phone_home": "",
    "ca_email_address": "REFROOM@TBHOLDINGS.COM",
    "ca_house_name": "Tracey Island",
    "ca_policy_data": "",
    "ca_customer_num": 2,
    "ca_first_name": "Scott",
    "ca_house_num": "",
    "ca_postcode": "TB14TV"
  }
  }
  }`

And so on. Now I have managed to read the JSON recors with ajax, but I have serious problems to pass that array of information outside the getCurrentJson function. Optimal situation would be that the first two parameters will be omitted so that there would be an array of user information for later manipulation in a "standard way" like this:

```
{
    "rows":[
        {"ca_customer_num":1", "ca_first_name:"Andrew",...}
        {"ca_customer_num":2", "ca_first_name:"Scott",...}
    ...
    ]
}
```

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON test</title>
          <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
          <script>
          var myjson = [];
          for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
              getCurrentJson(i);
              console.log(myjson[i].LGICUS01OperationResponse.ca.ca_phone_mobile);
          }

          function getCurrentJson(current){
            $.ajax({ 
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://192.49.208.193:9081/ci/c/"+current,
                success: function(data){
                    myjson[current] = data;
                    console.log(myjson[current]);
                    console.log(myjson[current].LGICUS01OperationResponse.ca.ca_phone_mobile);
                }
              });       
          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the console.log outputs inside ajax-function prints Object information and the "ca_phone_mobile" number fine, but the first console output in the for loop says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LGICUS01OperationResponse' of undefined(…)". Do I need some toString datatype conversion or similar? I have also tried to pass the myjson array to the getCurrentJson function but with no success.

Comment: `$.ajax` does an asynchronous call.  That is why your `console.log` in your for loop is not showing the expected result, the asynchronous request has not yet completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notice AJAX requests are asynchronous

PS: partial example below (also notice that not all requests have to be successful, some may fail and never get `done == total`)

```js
var myjson = [];
var total = 10;
var done = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
  getCurrentJson(i);
  // at this point AJAX request haven't finished (most likely)
  //console.log(myjson[i].LGICUS01OperationResponse.ca.ca_phone_mobile);
}

function allDone() {
  console.log(myjson);
}

function getCurrentJson(current){
  $.ajax({ 
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://192.49.208.193:9081/ci/c/"+current,
    success: function(data){
      myjson[current] = data;
      done++;
      console.log(myjson[current]);
      console.log(myjson[current].LGICUS01OperationResponse.ca.ca_phone_mobile);
      if (done == total) {
        allDone();
      }
    }
  }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to be working! :) It seems that trick is not to try syncing ajax with js but just let ajax make its own function call when it's ready.
However, the problem is that I would like to read c/"X" addresses as long as there is information. Server will just return empty values when the data is read through so I could just make a simple 'if (ca_last_name == "")' check instead of "(done == total)", but because of async ajax nature, I would need to have some infinite loop in the calling function and break it up somehow. Any hints how to do that? Thanks. :)

Comment: Yes, you'd have to loop until a flag is raised, such flag would be marked by the first request with no `ca_last_name` as you said. But notice that you'd need to detect when all your launched requests have all finished. For that you should handle on `complete` as that callback is "called when the request finishes (after `success` and `error` callbacks are executed).". Then for each launched request you'd (for instance) increase the `total` while on each `complete` callback you'd increase `done`, although you'd not stop on just `done==total`, but you also need to monitor your flag

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous you have to wait for response. For Now

```
console.log(myjson[i].LGICUS01OperationResponse.ca.ca_phone_mobile);
```

executing before you get response of your ajax request.So you should use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) or handle callback.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLPJNe

Comment: I assume that in the code snippet "cb" needs to written "callback". I tried that, but still got error:
_demo_callback.html:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LGICUS01OperationResponse' of undefined(…)_